# Count distinct messages by type/contactid

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that logs an activity for users:

AccountID/ContactID/Message/Time/Date are all logged.
Normally the message will be a colour, red, green etc...

Any AccountID can have several ContactID's

What i want to show is something like:

```
AccountID     Red    Green    Orange
Account1       4       5         0
Account2       3       4         1
Account3       5       2         1
```

It basically counts the distinct number of messages 
What i tried was:

```
select 
  AccountID, 
  count(distinct message where message = 'RED'), 
  count(distinct message where message = 'Green'), 
  count(distinct message where message = 'Orange') 
from
  activities 
where 
  date like '2013-01%';
```

But it returns an error 1064, i dont think my `count(distinct....)` is even close to being valid, but I can't find any examples or even what I should use. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Your `date` column's data type is char/varchar?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by combining CASE statements with the SUM aggregate function. Example:

```
select 
  AccountID, 
  sum(case when message = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) red_msgs, 
  sum(case when message = 'green' then 1 else 0 end) green_msgs, 
  sum(case when message = 'orange' then 1 else 0 end) orange_msgs, 
from
  activities 
where 
  `date` like '2013-01%'
group by 
  AccountID;
```

Comment: Tom Mac has (correctly) used standard SQL - but in MySQL you also use a shorthand SUM(x = y) - or maybe MAX(SUM(x=y))

Comment: Thank you for adding that, Strawberry. FWIW I prefer to use standard SQL since I often have to work in multiple RDBMSs: And minimizing translation time from one system to another may keep me employed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CASE`:

```
SELECT AccountID, 
  SUM(CASE message WHEN 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Red, 
  SUM(CASE message WHEN 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Green,
  SUM(CASE message WHEN 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Orange,
FROM activities 
WHERE date like '2013-01%';
```

Comment: I see @bernie beat me to it :-)

Comment: No worries, Jeff. You'll get the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate to Alternate to bernie's. Using if can be more readable.

```
select 
  AccountID, 
  sum(if(message = 'red'),1,0) red_msgs, 
  sum(if(message = 'green',1,0)) green_msgs, 
  sum(if(message = 'orange',1,0) orange_msgs, 
from
  activities 
where 
  date like '2013-01%'
group by 
  AccountID;
```